# Force Active Model Serializer to return association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, serialization, active-model-serializers

I have a [Active Model Serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) that has the following:

```
class API::DashboardSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :name, :special

    def special
        x = object.check_ins.first
        prev = x.prev_ci_with_weigh_in
    end
end
```

where `special` returns a record of class `CheckIn` and I'd like it to use the `CheckInSerailizer` for that record.  How can I force it to use the `CheckInSerializer` in `special`?

Comment: Remove `special` from `attributes` and then try `has_one` or `belongs_to` like `has_one :special, serializer: CheckInSerializer`

Comment: You should make this the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `special` from `attributes` and then try `has_one` or `belongs_to`, described in [this Guide](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/general/serializers.md#associations), like this:

```
class API::DashboardSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name

  has_one :special, serializer: CheckInSerializer

  def special
    # ...
```