# How to pass serializer for a relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name

  has_many :books, each_serializer: SimpleBookSerializer
end

class BookSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  # lots of attributes, associations
end

class SimpleBookSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title
end
```

Basically on the above snippet I am trying to restrict the attributes to only `id, name` from books, so I wrote a simple serializer which will return only id, title. But the default books serializer is getting invoked, and I am getting all the data which I don't require. How to prevent this

Comment: Try `has_many :books, serializer: SimpleBookSerializer`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259173/force-active-model-serializer-to-return-association/49381216#49381216

Comment: It worked, but it's supposed to be each_serializer right for multiple things?

Comment: `each_serializer` is worked in `render`. Inside ActiveModel::Serializer, DSL are same for `has_one`, `has many` etc, and works with `:serializer` option only. To get deeper, watch `active_model/serializer/reflection.rb`